# C#のvisual studioのヒントマークと専門用語の意味が知りたい

Tags: c#

ここですと書かれているコードの`{}`の中のコードなのですが`Width = fm.Width;`のWidthつまりLabelのWidthの意味をリファレンスページで調べたところ[コントロールの幅を取得または設定します。]と書かれているのですがコントロールとはどのような意味なのでしょうか？

１、コントロールの幅の意味が知りたい(操作?)

2,`Form fm = new Form(); fm.Test = "hello";`とするのと`Form fm = new Form(){/**/};`どちらも同じように捉えられるのですがどちらも見え方の問題でよろしいのでしょうか？

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

class CodeFile1
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Form fm = new Form()
        {
            Text = "サンプル",
            Width = 250,
            Height = 100,
        };

        string[][] str = new string[4][]
        {
            new string[] {"東京","TOKYOU","とうきょう","トウキョウ"},
            new string[] {"大阪","OOSAKA","おおさか"},
            new string[] {"名古屋","NAGOYA","なごや","ナゴヤ"},
            new string[] {"福岡","FUKUOKA","ふくおか"},
        };

        Label lb = new Label()//ここのコード
        {
            Width = fm.Width,
            Height = fm.Height,

        };

        string tmp = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        {
            tmp += "(";
            for(int j =0; j<str[i].Length; j++)
            {
                tmp += str[i][j];
                tmp += ",";
            }
            tmp += ")\n";           
        }

        lb.Text = tmp;
        lb.Parent = fm;

        Application.Run(fm);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> １、コントロールの幅の意味が知りたい(操作?)

この場合の「コントロール」は表示部品そのもののことと思ってください。なので「Labelコントロール」「Buttonコントロール」といった表現をよく使います。
なので、「Labelコントロールの幅」というのは「Labelを表示するときの横幅」という意味になります。

> 2,Form fm = new Form(); fm.Test = "hello";とするのとForm fm = new Form(){/**/};どちらも同じように捉えられるのですがどちらも見え方の問題でよろしいのでしょうか？

はい。動作は同じです。